# The process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Only the first time Navigaterecods() works, when it is called the second time it throws the exception:

> "The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process"

The filestream has been closed inside the sub everytime, yet it is throwing the same exception.
Could you please help me to fix this?

Thank you
M D Shivaram

```
Public Sub NavigateRecords()

Try
Dim fstrmImage As New FileStream("ASPE-Pyramid.jpg", FileMode.Create)

Dim blob As Byte() = DirectCast(DS.Tables("Pyramid").Rows(inc).Item(1), Byte())

fstrmImage.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length)
fstrmImage.Close()
fstrmImage = Nothing

PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("ASPE-Pyramid.jpg")
PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
PictureBox1.Refresh()
TextBox1.Text = DS.Tables("Pyramid").Rows(inc).Item(2).ToString
TextBox2.Text = DS.Tables("Pyramid").Rows(inc).Item(3).ToString
TextBox3.Text = DS.Tables("Pyramid").Rows(inc).Item(4).ToString
TextBox4.Text = DS.Tables("Pyramid").Rows(inc).Item(5).ToString
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You should bind those `TextBoxes` to your `DataTable` rather than populating them manually.

Comment: Pretty standard failure mode, Image.FromFile() puts a lock on the file with a memory-mapped file object to optimize the image access.  Simplest way to fix it is to replace the statement with `New Bitmap("ASPE-Pyramid.jpg")` so it makes an in-memory copy of the image data.

Comment: Could you please brief on this? i am new to VB.NET.

Comment: You should use `fstrmImage.Dispose()`, not set it to Nothing.

Comment: Or better yet, wrap it in a `Using` block.

Answer (score 1):

The `Image.FromFile` method locks the file until the `Image` object created is disposed, as the documentation clearly states.  You're not disposing the `Image` so the file remains locked.  You would need to dispose the current `Image` object, if there is one, before writing to the file again.

```
PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
Dim fstrmImage As New FileStream("ASPE-Pyramid.jpg", FileMode.Create)
```

If you want to avoid that, call the `PictureBox.Load` method and pass the file path instead.  That will not lock the file at all.

Of course, one has to wonder why you need to create a file at all.  A better option would be to create a `MemoryStream` with the image data and call `Image.FromStream`.  Just be aware that you need to keep the `MemoryStream` around as long as you need the `Image`, so that means disposing the previous `MemoryStream` before creating a new one and creating the last `MemoryStream` when you know you need no more.

Comment: I have changed the code using Image.FromStream. but,now it shows error at the last line(frm4.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized) of menuitem_click event.    Could you please let me know why is this?                                                                                                                         Private Sub PEProfileMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PEProfileMenuItem.Click
ActiveMdiChild.Close()
Dim frm4 As New PEProfilefrm
frm4.MdiParent = Me
frm4.Show()
frm4.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Comment: Code of any length is too hard to read in a comment, especially unformatted.  Please update your question with your new code and tell us what the error is, rather than just that there is one.

Comment: I have changed the code to Image.FromStream. it is ok now.      but shows error in menuitem_click event at the last  line : (frm4.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized)    The error is as follows..                                                                                                                                                                                                                        System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message="Parameter is not valid."
  Source="System.Drawing".

Comment: The code has been changed as given below but still shows the error:                                                                   Dim MyImage As Image = Image.FromStream(fstrmImage)
PictureBox1.Image = MyImage
MyImage.Dispose()
MyImage = Nothing

Comment: Did you miss the part where I said not to post unformatted code in comments but to update your question instead?

Comment: ok, the code has been changed as suggested and it is ok with that part. But shows an error message when the forms show method and the window state is maximized. May i know your solution to this?